# Creating custom implementation of navigation bar

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, uiscrollview, uinavigationbar

I wish to create a view similar in behavior to the `UINavigationBar`.

I cannot simply customize the bar as I want the space to be taller and I want to have several other subviews on it other than just `UIBarButtonItem`s. So, I want to be able to create a similar implementation including the floating/translucency effect.

I good example of this is the address bar in Safari in iOS 7. The `UITextField` on the bar is something that cannot be added on the default `UINavigationBar`. Nevertheless, the Safari bar still has the transparency.

I do not want it to shrink like it does in Safari when scrolling down, I simply want it to remain just like a `UINavigationBar` would. I was thinking about adding a subview to the root `UIScrollView`, but this would scroll along with everything. I want this to remain at the top, but I want other elements to be able to scroll.

How would I go about implementing this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are confident that you can't to this with the default UINavigationBar, you could shrink (from the top) the UIScrollView with whatever the size the  custom UINavigationBar is and then add the navbar as a subview to the root view at (0,0) coordinates. It will be independent from the scroll view.

On the other hand, if you need this to be persistent through the application and use it in all of the screens, it will be wise to make some changes starting for the *AppDelegate*, but that's for another question.

For the iOS 7 transparent-style part, look here: [FXBlurView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXBlurView). Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for your response! If I decrease the UIScrollView size, when I scroll, the content will never go up and show through the custom navigation bar. Is there a way to have the UIScrollView fill up the whole screen and have the custom navigation bar layered on top of it? Also, what exactly would the custom navigation bar be? A UILabel with a background color?

Comment: Do you have any ideas?